# How we can save a Hazelcast map entry in a database or a file when the entry reaches its Time To Live?

Tags: hazelcast

In my application, we are using Hazelcast and an oracle DB.

When we start a transition, we put an entry containing the transition id in a Hazelcast map.

If that transition id is consumed within the TTL, it is fine. My application used it and the same thread evicts that entry from hazelcast map and save that transition id in the database.  **No issue**

My issue comes when that transition id is not consumed within its TTL. Hazelcast simply removes that entry from the map.

I want to retrieve that entry and save it in the database.

How would you approach that problem? I am working  with Hazelcast running in a cluster with at least 4 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to store Hazelcast Map via [Mapstore Interface](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/manual/html-single/#loading-and-storing-persistent-data) so even though TTL enabled data is evicted, it will be kept in your backing store.

The other solution is to catch the evicted entries and store it some backing store.

Here is a sample application that you can try yourself.

```
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<String, String> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("test");
    map.addEntryListener(new EntryEvictedListener<String,String>() {
        @Override
        public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String, String> entryEvent) {
            System.out.println(entryEvent.getKey() + ":" + entryEvent.getOldValue());
        }
    },true);
    map.put( "1", "John", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

After 10 seconds, you will see that entry is evicted and printed out to the console.

The events are sent to all nodes so it can be better to implement **EntryListenerConfig**, add it to MapConfig and set **local** parameter true to receive only local events.

Please see [Registering Map Listeners](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.4/manual/html-single/#registering-map-listeners) for more info.